# NodeJS - Multer - optional image upload on multiple images

Tags: node.js, multer

**User** field multiple image upload is available, but it is optional.

As I know, Multer preserves ordering in array of images so I have no problem mapping if every User have image.

Problem is if 5th User dont have image, I will have 7 images in the array, and would map it to the wrong entry.

```
  const upload = multer({storage: fileStorageEngine}).fields(
      [
        {
          name: 'House',
          maxCount: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'User',
          maxCount: 8
        }
      ]
  )

  // Create a new House
  router.post("/", (req,res) => {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        return "An error occurred"
      }

      console.log(req.files)

      const payload = JSON.parse(req.body.data)
      // payload.image = req.file.path
      house.create(req, payload, res)
    })
  });
```

Solutions for this problem worth considering:

- I can rename every image when sending from frontend so I would know to which object in payload should I map the image path
- Add to multer fields object in the array like this, so after this check each if image exists...

```
const upload = multer({storage: fileStorageEngine}).fields(
    [
      {
        name: 'House',
        maxCount: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'User1',
        maxCount: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'User2',
        maxCount: 1
      },
      ........
    ]
)
```

Both of this solutions to me is not something I would like to implement so maybe there is better solution for this problem.

Thanks :)